# Custom scrollTo function for nested scrollable div doesn't work in Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, animation, scrolltop

I'm using Google Polymer to make a web app, although I don't think this problem is specific to that.

Basically, I'm building a scrollTo function that animates to a location I pass in (px location from top of scrollable div). This work like a charm in Chrome, but doesn't work at all in Firefox. Specifically, setting the scrollTop property doesn't move scroll the div so there is no animation or movement when this function is called (again, it works in chrome). I believe it has to do with setting the scrollTop property, as I've seen many problems with it in other posts.

However, those posts all either use jQuery or only fix the problem for scrolls that take up the entire page (body, html). I need a solution that that works (and only needs to work) for a nested div with the css property overflow: auto or overflow: scroll.

I'm trying not to use external libraries, but if it's the only way, suggestions on lightweight ones are also appreciated :D Please no jQuery though!

```
  scrollTo: function ( to ) {

   // to is the location in pixels to animate to

    // div inside of body
    // for those not familiar with Polymer, this just gets the div
    // with id="scrollableArea"
    var element = this.$.scrollableArea;

    // also, for Polymer, "this." refers to properties for a web component
    if ( this.scrollAnimationTimeout ) {
      cancelAnimationFrame( this.scrollAnimationTimeout );
      this.scrollAnimationTimeout = null;
    }

    var start = element.scrollTop,
      change = to - start,
      increment = 20;

    var duration = 250;

    var animateScroll = function ( elapsedTime ) {
      elapsedTime += increment;
      element.scrollTop = this.easeInOut( elapsedTime, start, change, duration );

      if ( elapsedTime < duration ) {
        this.scrollAnimationTimeout = requestAnimationFrame( function () {
          animateScroll( elapsedTime );
        });
      }
    }.bind( this );

    animateScroll( 0 );
  },
```

The div is just a normal div with a css property of overflow: auto. I've also ensured that requestAnimationFrame exists with a polyfill, so I'm confident that that is not the problem (although I could be wrong).